# ubuntu xenial unattended-upgrade not working anymore

Tags: unattended-upgrades

I have xenial install in Virtualbox with Host Jessie.

Since a few weeks unattended-upgrade is not longer working. As workaround I update over a little "Script".

```
apt-config dump | egrep -i unatt
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";
Unattended-Upgrade "";
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins "";
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins:: "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}";
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins:: "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security";
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins:: "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";
Unattended-Upgrade::Mail "root";
```

Status from apt-daily

```
systemctl -a  | awk '{print $1}' | egrep '^apt' | xargs systemctl status

● apt-daily.service - Daily apt activities
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apt-daily.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:apt(8)

● apt-daily.timer - Daily apt activities
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apt-daily.timer; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (waiting) since Mo 2017-05-08 12:48:51 CEST; 57min ago

Mai 08 12:48:51 beelzemon systemd[1]: Started Daily apt activities
```

apt-daily is running since 12:48 today.

```
uptime
 13:48:23 up  1:00,  2 users,  load average: 0,02, 0,08, 0,08` show i started my Virtualbox at 13:48. `date
Mo 8. Mai 13:49:36 CEST 2017
```

But xenial is running ~45min. the same time discrepancy I have on my Host.

Is there a relation to my problem with unattended-upgrades?  So I can search in this direction?

I can not post `LANG=C unattended-upgrade -d -v --apt-debug` I get python-errors and the relevant output is in German.

For sure:

```
timedatectl status
      Local time: Mo 2017-05-08 14:13:59 CEST
  Universal time: Mo 2017-05-08 12:13:59 UTC
        RTC time: Mo 2017-05-08 12:13:57
       Time zone: Europe/Berlin (CEST, +0200)
 Network time on: yes
NTP synchronized: no
 RTC in local TZ: no` in xenial.
```

Edit found [Bug-Report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unattended-upgrades/+bug/1680599?comments=all)

I found my Error in 50unattended-upgrades

I tried to resolve why unattended-upgrades not run in the 1. Place. The problem is that apt-daily.service runs before I have Network-Access. Something wrong with apt-daily.timer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In another Forum we found a workaround, with some who had the same problem in yakkety. `sudo systemctl edit apt-daily.timer` Content

`[Unit] 
After=network-online.target 
Wants=network-online.target` This creates an override under `/etc/systemd/system/apt-daily.timer.d/override.conf` Today I get a mail from unattended-upgrades. :D